# how do i get my variables to be recognized?

Tags: r

I am writing a `dataframe` using a `csv` file. I am making a data frame. However, when I go to run it, it's not recognizing the objects in the file. It will recognize some of them, but not all.

```
smallsample <- data.frame(read.csv("SmallSample.csv",header = TRUE),smallsample$age,smallsample$income,smallsample$gender,smallsample$marital,smallsample$numkids,smallsample$risk)
smallsample
```

It wont recognize `marital` or `numkids`, despite the fact that those are the column names in the table in the `.csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `read.csv` the output is already in a dataframe. 
You can simple use `smallsample <- read.csv("SmallSample.csv")`

Result using a dummy csv file

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th> </th><th>age</th><th>income</th><th>gender</th><th>marital</th><th>numkids</th><th>risk</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>32</td><td>34932</td><td>Female</td><td>Single</td><td>1</td><td>0.9611315</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>22</td><td>50535</td><td>Male</td><td>Single</td><td>0</td><td>0.7257541</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>40</td><td>42358</td><td>Male</td><td>Single</td><td>1</td><td>0.6879534</td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>40</td><td>54648</td><td>Male</td><td>Single</td><td>3</td><td>0.568068</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: It says that the marital object isn't found

Comment: What have you tried and how does your csv look like?

Comment: its 500 rows with 6 columns. all clean data.

Comment: $ AGE    : int  
 $ INCOME : int  
 $ GENDER : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Female","Male":  $ MARITAL: Factor w/ 3 levels "divwidsep","married",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ NUMKIDS: int  1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ RISK   : Factor w/ 3 levels "bad loss","bad profit",..: 3 3 1 1 3 3 2 1 2 3 ...
> class(marital) <- as.factor(marital)
Error in is.factor(x) : object 'marital' not found
> class(numkids) <- as.integer(numkids)
Error: object 'numkids' not found
> class(marital)
Error: object 'marital' not found
> class(numkids)
Error: object 'numkids' not found

Comment: try `as.factor(SmallSample$marital)`. I think your are not referring to the `df` correctly - as it is you are calling a df called `marital` when marital is a column within the `df`

Comment: Well, that's funny. We always recommend new users [not to use screenshots of code or alphanumeric output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6574038), but you answer in this bad style. Please edit your question accordingly and avoid this in future, thanks.

Comment: @PatrickMurray, your sample output a few comments above indicates that the column name is `MARITAL`, not `marital`.  R is case sensitive, so that's why it wasn't being found.

Comment: Fair enough, @jay.sf . Table format in SO is horrible though (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables)